# Destroying COM object in Delphi

Tags: .net, delphi, com

Have some .net assembly, calling it in delphi through COM.

```
var
   intf: ITest;

...
   intf:= CreateComObject(CLASS_TEST) as ITest;
   ...
   //here comes some stuff
   ...
```

Must i do something to destruct it to free memory. Or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should better release the memory with

```
       intf := nil;
```

When you don't need it any more. Better with a `try...finally intf := nil;` block, or in the `Destroy` overriden method if `intf` is defined as `fIntf`, i.e. as a class property.

If `intf` is defined on stack, it will we freed automatically at the end of the method. There is an hidden `try...finally intf := nil; end` block generated  by the compiler to free the `intf` instance.

Comment: i'm not familiar with delphi. what do u mean by saying 'defined on stack', every variable defined at var section, so they are all on stack?

Comment: Yes it's in stack. So Delphi will release this reference at the end of the method. If intf is stored in an object field it will release it during object destruction.

Comment: p.s. When I say "release" I do not insist that the referenced object will be destroyed, its behavior depends on how was it designed. p.p.s.Assigning a nil to an interface reference is needed when you want to release the object sooner, i.e. if you want to control the order of releasing.

Comment: -1 because it is not true that you "should" release the memory. This is completely optional.

Comment: @Fred I wrote "should" because I found out that, for instance, some Delphi compilers (and not old one, I'm speaking about Delphi 2010) [do not produce the code they had too for `object`](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=210), even if they "should" and are documented to do so... I was therefore not 100% sure it will always be the case. I'm happy if you are so confident and that no such issue ever occurred with interfaces. Of course, I know `object` is deprecated, and interfaces are not... ;)

Comment: @Frederik, If releasing memory is optionnal to you, remind me to never use a software you created.

Comment: I think Frederik meant that you don't have to set an interface variable  to nil for the object to get destroyed

Comment: There are bugs with interface reference counting most notably passing a newly created object to a const function parameter without assigning to a local variable first. Compiler should create implicit local variable but fails to do so. Bug has been present since forever.

Comment: @jack I hope your acceptance of this answer doesn't mean you believe that interfaces need to be manually released. They don't.

Comment: @Ken: Please read the rules for interface variables in Delphi first. They are released automatically by the compiler when they go out of scope. Perhaps my comment was not clear, obviously I meant that it is NOT correct that you "should" set the variable to nil. Either way it will be released. Sometimes though, you need to control exactly when the release needs to take place, and in that case assigning nil is the answer.

Comment: @Frederik, That would be true for anything that is finalized. For threadvars, you need to do it manually. For dynamic arrays of interface too I believe. (Unless you can pass it to Finalize). And for global variables, since the variable never goes out of scope, it might be wanted to release the memory after the work is over. So yeah, even though most of the time, setting interface variable to nil is not necessary, there are still many situations where it's required.

Comment: @ken that's the position that @frederik has taken the whole time.

Comment: @David, Fredirik's position is that it's never needed to assign nil to an interface variable as it will *always* get released anyway. I'm saying there are situations where interfaces won't get release unless you release them manually. (i.e. Arrays reserved with GetMem, threadvars, etc)

Comment: @Ken No, @Frederik's position is that interfaces will always get released at some point, but that you can release them ahead of time if you wish.  You examples of arrays allocated with GetMem and threadvars are bogus and have nothing to do with interface reference counting.

Comment: @David, they have nothing to do about interface reference counting... Beside the fact that they are breaking it.

Answer (score 12):

COM objects are reference-counted, and they get automatically destroyed when the reference count reaches zero. The compiler will automatically add calls to `_AddRef` and `_Release` interface methods whenever your code adds a reference to the object or removes it. Setting a variable referencing a COM object to `nil` will call `_Release` (decrementing the reference count), and if the reference count reaches zero the object is also freed (it won't be if the reference count is not zero). When a variable goes out of scope (i.e. a local variable, when the procedure exits), the compiler will also call `_Release` if the variable references a COM object (or any reference-counted Delphi interface).

Answer (score 7):

All COM interfaces must implement `IUnknown`:

```
IUnknown = interface
  function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
  function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
  function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
end;
```

`IUnknown` provides two services. First of all, `QueryInterface` allows for clients to obtain the other interfaces that the object may implement.  The second service is that of lifetime management.

Every time you take a reference to a COM object it is your responsibility to call `_AddRef`.  Every time you give up a reference to a COM object, you are contracted to call `_Release`.

The canonical implementation of `_AddRef` and `_Release` is for the implementing object to maintain a reference count variable which is incremented and decremented as references are taken and released. If a call to `_Release` sets this reference count to 0 then the object destroys itself.

The Delphi implementation of interfaces manages the calls to `_AddRef` and `_Release` on your behalf. When you assign to an interface variable the compiler emits code that:

- Calls `_Release` on the interface that the variable previously referred to, if indeed it did previously refer to something.
- Calls `_AddRef` on the interface that the variable now refers to.

The compiler also arranges for `_Release` to be called whenever the variable leaves scope.

What this means is that you need to take no special action whatsoever to ensure that your COM objects will be destroyed.  They will naturally be destroyed when the last reference to the object leaves scope.

If however, you do wish to destroy an object ahead of time, then you simply assign `nil` to the variable holding the interface.  Note that this is of course presuming that no other references are held to that interface.

Answer (score 2):

The object is released automatically. However, if you explicitly want to release the reference that the `intf` variable holds, you can set it to nil.