# Calling a C# .Net method that has ref String arguments from Delphi 7

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, com

Revised question:

We're using D7 to call a C# method that's in a COM object. The C# method returns a WideString.

Is there a risk that .NET will garbage collect the returned WideString from under our feet while we're using it in our Pascal code? If so, what alternatives do we have to safely return a string from a C# COM object?

Also, is our final Delphi line SubMan := nil the proper way to release the COM object?

**C# Code**

```
    [DispId(5)] 
    bool Test(int var1, ref int var2, ref string var3); 


    public bool Test(int var1, ref int var2, ref string var3) 
    { 
        bool result; 
        if (var1 == 0) 
        { 
            var2 = 0; 
            var3 = "zero"; 
            result = true; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            var2 = -1; 
            var3 = "minus one"; 
            result = false; 
        } 
        return result; 
    }
```

**Pascal code from generated TLB in D7**

```
function Test(     var1: Integer; 
               var var2: Integer; 
               var var3: WideString): WordBool; dispid 5;
```

**Pascal code calling the COM object. Is there a risk var3 will be GC-ed?**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SubMan: TSubMan;
  Var1: Integer;
  Var2: Integer;
  Var3: WideString;
  FunctionResult: Boolean;
begin
  SubMan :=  COTSubMan.Create;
  Var1 := 1;
  FunctionResult :=  SubMan.Test(Var1, Var2, Var3);  
  // Will Var3 above be persistent in the code 
  // or might it be garbage collected by .NET before we can use it below or later?
  ShowMessage( BoolToStr(FunctionResult, TRUE) + 
               ' Var2 = ' + IntToStr(Var2) + 
               ' Var3 = ' + Var3);
  SubMan := nil;  // Is this the right way to release the COM object?
end;
```

Comment: Please post the code in the C# `Test` method and the code in the Dephi client that calls `Test`.  Does the `EOleSysError` happen calling into the method or returning from the method?

Comment: If it's COM then use the COM string. Question lacks details.

Comment: The code you have added is incomplete. Show the complete C# class declaration.

Comment: Var3 (WideString) is reference counted. It will be deallocated when it leaves scope, i.e. when your method `Button1Click()` ends.

Comment: @LURD Just to confirm, even though the string was _originally_ allocated in the C# COM object, var3 is safe to use throughout our Delphi Button1Click method?  That's great news.  May I ask _how_ that happens?  Is the var3 string a _copy_ of the C# string that is created by Delphi as the COM call comes back from C#?

Comment: C# code should use `BSTR` type instead of string. See [`BSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `If you pass a simple Unicode string as an argument to a COM function that is expecting a BSTR, the COM function will fail.`.

Comment: About how to release a COM-object, see [`Destroying COM object in Delphi`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6476353/576719). You must use the interface type of the COM-object. Since it is reference counted it will be implicitly destroyed when it leaves scope.

Comment: @LURD By "If you pass a simple Unicode string as an argument to a COM function that is expecting a BSTR, the COM function will fail.." does it mean that we should pass a WideString or some other type?

Comment: WideString is a Delphi type that equals BSTR, in C# you would have to declare a similar COM interface, something like  `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr] out string Var3` for the Var3 parameter. Sorry if I'm sounding vague here, C# is not a language I use. I'm sure @DavidHeffernan can explain further, now parts of your C# code is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your question is fine. The COM marshaller handles the lifetimes of the two `ref` parameters for you. There's no danger from the GC because the semantics of the parameters is clearly expressed. The objects that you work with on the Delphi side are not .net objects and so not subject to GC.

Indeed, the GC is not a factor because this is COM. The fact that there is a .net object on the other side implemented the COM server is neither here nor there. It's the responsibility of the .net COM interop layer to present a valid COM object to you.

> Just to confirm, even though the string was originally allocated in the C# COM object, var3 is safe to use throughout our Delphi Button1Click method?

Yes. Remember that this is COM, a standard for binary interop. You don't need to be too concerned by the details. FWIW, a `WideString` is the Delphi wrapper around the COM `BSTR` type. That string type is a UTF-16 encoded string, reference counted, and allocated off the shared COM heap. That last point is important. The fact that `BSTR` instances come of the shared COM heap is what allows them to be allocated in one module, and deallocated in another.

> Is `SubMan := nil` the proper way to release the COM object?

Yes it is. Although it is a little pointless in this code because the local variable is about to leave scope and that will have the exact same effect as your `nil` assignment.

Comment: THANK YOU, @DavidHefferman!  I really appreciate your taking the time to answer. As usual, the breadth and depth of your technical knowledge astonishes me! Thanks again for all of your help, not only on this question, but so many!

Comment: That's very kind of you. Thanks. I'm amazed nobody else had chipped in. I'd have answer sooner had you prodded me! Thanks to @LURD for doing so.

Comment: @DavidHefferman: Hey, I'd been waiting and hoping you'd pop in, David. And, if I knew how to prod you, I would have!

Comment: You just did prod me with @NameOfProdee

Answer (score 0):

Using [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) type is the easiest way since COM will handle memory (de)allocation.

eg:

Delphi:

```
function ReturnString(out TheString: WideString): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  try
    TheString := 'Hello World';
  finally
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool ReturnString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]out string TheString);
```

Comment: I think you may have reversed the caller-callee scenario I am using. I've revised the question, hopefully making it clearer.